# How stored relations between pages and app hook in django-cms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-cms

I can not find it in pagemodel.py or  directly in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your asking how the `Page` model in django CMS knows it's relation to it's Apphooks, it is stored in the `application_urls` field:

https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/7888ab8421bb836c8f7a1127d9a2bf4d4bbdf23e/cms/models/pagemodel.py#L82

That field will hold the **class name** of your apphook. You can thus get the apphook class from a page object using `apphook_pool.get_apphook(page.application_urls)`.